# fabric peer instantiate throws err MSP DEFAULT is unknown

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

```
    #cli 环境变量 
CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/run/docker.sock
CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
CORE_PEER_ID=cli
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:7051
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DEFAULT
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=./msp
```

I want to execute peer instantiate chaincode, I do not want user docker exec -it cli bash, I want to execute it in ubuntu terminal, I set the environment variable, but throws  err MSP DEFAULT is unknown Exception.

> Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Failed to deserialize creator identity, err MSP DEFAULT is unknown
>   Usage:
>     peer chaincode instantiate [flags]
>   Flags:

could somebody tell me why?and how to modify?

Comment: It seems to be an error related with the creation of the crypto material. How do you create that material? Which steps did you executed previously?

Comment: It happened to me in the case of to instantiate chaincode on newly created peer, which joined existing channel after channel update and under a new organization(new mspid). For your case, would you like to check whether consortium config insides ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE block file includes MSP named 'DEFAULT'?